# What is the size limit of the application object in classic asp?

Tags: caching, asp-classic, vbscript

I am creating an ASP script that uses the application object to store the pages. The question in my mind is whether there is a size limit to this object. Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application pool may specifiy the Maximum virtual memory size that a worker process can allocate.  This is setting will affect the maximum size of data that the application object can hold.

If this setting is not specified (or is larger than 2GB) then another factor will be whether the process is running in 32 Bit mode.  If so then you could only expect to get a maximum of 1.5GB (if that) in the application object regardless of how much memory is present on the server.

On 64 bit server running the worker process as a 64 bit process it would be able to consume as much RAM and pagefile that it can get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure there's no explicit limit - but of course at some point you will use up so much memory that you'll see other effects - e.g. your application being recycled because it has exceeded its memory limit, or your application grinding to a halt as the server runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the limit is really the RAM of the hosting server. If you have a very large number of pages, using a database or files for less frequently accessed pages may be helpful, but i have never seen any specific issues with a hard limit.