# Is there a maximum number of INCLUDES in a Classic ASP page?

Tags: asp-classic, include, limits

I'm making some updates to a Classic ASP page and I've noticed that when I add a lot of INCLUDES (ie. `<!--#INCLUDE FILE="Foo.asp" -->`), I get a generic "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error" displayed in bold on the page.

This is notable in part because I normally get detailed error messages (error, file, line, etc.)

I've checked that none of those INCLUDES have errors. It seems like it has to do with the number of INCLUDES or the fully compiled size of the .asp file.

Is this something I can fix in the ASP settings for IIS?

Comment: Have you checked individually all includes? It can be an error in some included page instead of a limit

Comment: Yes, as I stated above, I have checked all of the Includes and there are no errors.

Comment: You say you're getting a generic 500 error - have you enabled friendly error messages - this might help you pinpoint the problem.
http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: Y, I do. I normally get detailed error messages with the error code, line number, page, etc. But this is a message that reads "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error".

Answer (score 1):

I never heard about a limitation of includes. but it is possible that your result-page is too large. 
Did you remove some all includes and put them back step by step?

Alternately i prefer a type of dynamical includes.
With my following function you have some advantages: you can include a file dynamically. Your result page will only include the neccascary files. Variables from the main script can be used in the included files. You can put the asp-code into a database.

But this way has one limitation: The whole included file must be written in ASP. So it's not allowed to use <%= date %>. It must be written as 
response.write date

I'm using a function to include asp-files:

```
function fGet(getFile)
' source: http://www.aspfaq.de/index.asp?FID=14&ELE=1223
                Set objFileSys = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sPfad=Server.MapPath("./")&"\" &getFile

    Set objFile = objFileSys.OpenTextFile(sPfad)
        ' --- read the file
        FileContent = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFileSys = Nothing

     fileContent=replace(fileContent,chr(60)&chr(37),"")
     fileContent=replace(fileContent,chr(37)&chr(62),"")

     Execute(FileContent)


end function
```

Comment: Great reply and very helpful script! Thanks, but doesn't quite answer my question. Do you know if there is a limit to the ASP result-page? I've searched and can't find anything mentioned. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/asp/limits

Comment: my reply began with "I never heard about a limitation of includes" I just beleive, that you have a problem with the memory. Did you removed all includes and  put them in again step by step?

Comment: i just made a small test. a file with more than 100 includes. No problems!

Comment: thanks! I've also made a test file with many includes. Same result as your test. I think that it must have to do with the size of the final page but I can't find any info online on the limits of an ASP page.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161712/what-is-the-size-limit-of-the-application-object-in-classic-asp?utm_medium=organic or check the settings in your IIS-Server under "ASP". Maybe you can change the settings for Cache or Limits

Answer (score 1):

Try `<%response.buffer = false%>`. It defaults to `true` in IIS5.0 and later and must be explicitly switched off. It should be the very first line of code beneath the `@LANGUAGE` directive.

Turning off this buffer will free up resources so you won't hit your maximum. Increasing cache size isn't always feasible on shared hosting which is where you are likely to encounter size limits.

Comment: Good idea. Will check this out. Thanks!